# How to ignore to install some R packages when building a new R package?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I am building a new R package using Rstudio.
For one R function of my R package, I need to use another R package wrote by others. Generally, I have to list the R package in the row "Imports" of the file "DESCRIPTION".
Since this R function is not a main function of my R package and it takes a bit longer time to install the required R package, I would like to know if it is possible to ignore during the installation of my new R package?
When I tried to do it, I get the below error:
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Namespace dependencies missing from DESCRIPTION Imports/Depends entrie: ...

Comment: try this install.packages("package", dependencies = FALSE). Not sure if works. Alternatives here:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages

Comment: Are you saying that R keeps reinstalling the same package over and over each time you install your package? That doesn’t seem right. Once the package is installed it should not be installed again. Are you using docker containers or something? We need more details to replicate and diagnose the problem

Comment: Maybe put the package in `Suggests` or `Enhances` and use an `if` condition in your package code that checks if the package is installed? See "Writing R extensions".

Comment: I tried to put the package in Suggests, but still got the same warning. My question might not clear. For the users of my package, they may not need to install this required package until they run a specific R function (this function doesn't often use for most users of my package).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing "@imports package" in the related R function

Comment: Well, then the function that depends on that package simply won't work anymore.